Inquiry regarding my MSc degree in Mathematical Physics
I did my post graduation (MSc) in the branch Mathematical Physics in India. I have qualified national level Mathematics examination for this. Now I want to pursue my PhD in Mathematics but I am feeling like a dilemma. Although I understand that this is an interdisciplinary branch of Math and Physics but am I eligible to pursue my career in Math or should I have to switch over to Physics. Is there any Mathematical body or Association who can clarify my dilemma regarding my eligibility. Is Mathematical Physics more towards Mathematics or physics?

Note: this question has been asked first on math.stackexchange here

does this question & answer helps you? (it's about physics and maths https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/110352/what-is-the-eligibility-criteria-for-doing-research-in-physics)

@JackRed Actually I want to ask how can I show that mathematical Physics is indeed a branch of Applied Mathematics. Is there any research article or book to act as  supporting evidence for me?

I would advice to edit your question then, to clarify it and express exactly what you want. You should check out how to ask a good question and what types of questions you shouldn't ask

how can I show that mathematical Physics is indeed a branch of Applied Mathematics --- I would think anyone in applied mathematics (and many in pure mathematics) evaluating your application would have enough background knowledge to judge your background. And, assuming (which seems reasonable to me) that nearly everyone applying to a competitive program is "qualified", for competitive programs the actual issue would be whether you are better (in whatever way is being used to make such a judgement) than x% of the applicants, where x% is the percentage of applicants that can be chosen.

mathematical physics is mathematics.
